# saving and retrieving saved checkbox values from local storage in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, local-storage, onsen-ui

I am new to angularjs and phonegap. I am trying to build an app where on a page, a user can select a category from say 9 categories. I am putting a checkbox beside each category name for the user to select the categories. After selecting a few categories(by checking the respective checkboxes), the user can press the save button for the categories to be saved. My question is how do I save all those categories and how do I retrieve them?

This is the code I have so far

```
<!--html code --> <!-- the items here the titles of the categories pulled from a data.js file-->
<div ng-repeat="row in items | partition:3">
<div ng-repeat="item in row"">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="(item.title)">
<div>{{item.title}}</div>

<ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="savecategories()">Ready</ons-button>
```

/*angularjs code */

```
 app.controller('categoryController', function($scope) {
 $scope.savecategories = function() {
    if ($scope.category1)
     { 
        localStorage.setItem('category1', true);
    }
    else {
        localStorage.setItem('category2', false);
   if ($scope.category2)
     { 
        localStorage.setItem('category2', true);
    }
   else {
          localStorage.setItem('category2', false);
        }

   /*and so on */
      } 
   });
```

I tried to see if it is working by putting this line of code so that I would get an alert but no luck.

```
var national = localStorage.getItem('category1');
window.alert(national);
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add alert in this SaveCategories and check if this function is called, I think its savecategories

Comment: my bad, spelled it wrong here. Corrected it. :)

Comment: There is something that i don't understand, could you tell me what is $scope.category1 ?

Comment: sorry, $scope.category1 is the first category (checkbox) name. So since there are nine categories, their names from ng-model="item.title" are like category1, category2, and so on

Comment: So i added the alert box for category 1 like above @Reena. It is showing the alert box but it is showing false even when the category1 checkbox is checked so which means the function is being called but the values aren't being passed maybe?

Comment: Try this, savecategories(item.tiltle),  then $scope.savecategories = function(item) {  }    u need to pass the parameter,   you are checking if($scope.category1)  from where will it gets the value???

Comment: Actually you don't need theses "if" clauses. just writing localStorage.setItem('category1', $scope.category1); would behave the same. Your ng-model binds your checkbox values to items.row.title, you will not get it with $scope.category1. If you make a plunker i could correct this point easier for you.

Comment: mind doing it in stypi? https://code.stypi.com/izgbf57p

Comment: Make an object where keys are category names and values are true/false. Change values on click in its respective checkbox and store/retrieve the object as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. I figured it out finally. I just added a function which is called everytime a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.value" name="item.title" ng-change="savecategories()">
```

In my js file, I did this:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, Data, localStorageService) {

    $scope.items = Data.items;

    if (localStorageService.get('items')) {
        $scope.items = localStorageService.get('items');
    }

    $scope.SaveCategories = function () {
    localStorageService.clearAll();
    localStorageService.add('items',$scope.items);

    }
```